# How can I set zsh as the default shell on MSYS2 in Windows 10?

Tags: shell, windows-10, zsh, default, msys2

Is there a way to set **zsh** as the default shell in **MSYS2** on **Windows 10**?

When I ran the command: `chsh -s $(which zsh)`, it says: `sudo: chsh command not found`.

What should I do to use zsh on windows? **My computer does not support WSL.**

The terminal says: `Command not found` whenever I run the `chsh` command.

Comment: Already answered on the proper site: [Change default shell on MSYS2](https://superuser.com/q/961699/439609) (to zsh)

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the better way, instead of fooling around with MSYS shell, is to add zsh to your windows terminal setup, then you can choose from a number of shells, whether cmd, powershell, zsh, wsl or whatever. Install Windows Terminal from the MS store. Go into settings. Click Add a new profile. Add the location of zsh in there as the command. If you wish, set it as the default shell for Windows Terminal

Comment: I am unable to install WSL, I think it is because my Computer is a bit outdated and its hardware is not good enough for WSL. My Microsoft Store is broken. It doesn't let me install any software. Can you explain how I can add zsh to my Windows Terminal profile?

Comment: @TharunRaj I just explained it. You go into Windows terminal settings, click "Add a new profile". Add the location of zsh as the command. There's tons of places on the internet with more in depth explanations, but it's really as easy as that. You don't need wsl. Note that Windows Terminal is not the same as the CMD.com old style terminal, which is probably what MSYS uses.

Comment: I will try doing this.